# Django Bootstrap modal forms missing csrf token

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, bootstrap-modal, csrf-token

I'm using django bootstrap modal forms for login and signup popups but they're missing csrf tokens, i get "CSRF token from POST incorrect." error when signing up or logging in.

I have `{% csrf token %}` in my html templates so that's not the problem. I've seen lots of answers to this problem with views reconfigurations (adding method decorators and form to render context) but since i'm using class-based view from bootstap modal forms documentation example I can't repeat such solutions. My views look like this:

```
class CustomLoginView(BSModalLoginView):
        authentication_form = CustomAuthenticationForm
        template_name = 'login.html'
        success_message = 'Success: You were successfully logged in.'
        extra_context = dict(success_url=reverse_lazy('home'))

class SignUpView(BSModalCreateView):
        form_class = CustomUserCreationForm
        template_name = 'signup.html'
        success_message = 'Success: Sign up succeeded. You can now Log in.'
        success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

I've tried rewriting them with methods like this:

```
class SignUpView(BSModalCreateView):

        def signup_view(request):
            form = CustomUserCreationForm()
            if request.method == "GET":
                return render(request, 'signup.html', context={'form':form})
            if request.method == "POST":
                data = request.POST
                if form.is_valid():
                    user = form.save(False)
                    user.set_password(user.password)
                    user.save()

                    return redirect('home')
```

but then forms stop working. Also, I've tried adding CsrfExemptMixin from django-braces but that didn't work either. The only solution that worked is disabling csrf checks completely but I really want to keep them since it's safer. Am I missing something? How these class-based views can be changed so that csrf token starts working?

Answer (score 0):

turn off CSRF and have no protection

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).